# Missing body, or declare abstract java error message

Tags: java

I have to make an object-oriented program for an assignment, I get the same error on both line 9 and 30. I know that I'm trying to create the Celsius and Fahrenheit objects wrong, but I am not sure how to do it correctly.

```
import java.io.*;
class Celsius
{

        String inData;
        int celsius;
        int temperature;

    Celsius();
    {
     InputStreamReader inStream = new InputStreamReader (System.in);
         BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader (inStream);

     System.out.println("Enter a temperature in degres fahrenheit.");
     inData = stdin.readLine();
     temperature = Integer.parseInt(inData);

     celsius = (5 / 9) * (temperature - 32);
     System.out.println("Your temperature in degrees celsius is: " + celsius);
    }
}

class Fahrenheit
{

    String inData;
    int fahrenheit;
    int temperature;

    Fahrenheit();
    {
     InputStreamReader inStream = new InputStreamReader (System.in);
         BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader (inStream);

     System.out.println("Enter a temperature in degrees celsius.");
     inData = stdin.readLine();
     temperature = Integer.parseInt(inData);

      fahrenheit = (9 / 5) * temperature + 32;
      System.out.println("Your temperature in degrees fahrenheit is: " +  fahrenheit);
}
}

class TemperatureTest
{

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
InputStreamReader inStream = new InputStreamReader (System.in);
    BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader (inStream);
String inData;
int selection;

System.out.println("Input 1 to convert fahrenheit to celsius");
System.out.println("Input 2 to convert celsius to fahrenheit");


inData = stdin.readLine();
selection = Integer.parseInt(inData);

if (selection == 1)
{
 Celsius c1 = new Celsius();
}

if (selection == 2)
{
 Fahrenheit f1 = new Fahrenheit();
}

if (selection != 1 & selection != 2)
{
  System.out.println("Invalid selection.");
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Format your code and you will find the problem. Also, you are performing integer division.

Comment: That's too much work to do in a constructor; make those into `void` functions instead.

Answer (score 2):

The errors are on your constructors:

```
Celsius();
{
```

and

```
Fahrenheit();
{
```

There should be no semicolon between a constructor/method and its block.  Remove those semicolons:

```
Celsius()
{

Fahrenheit()
{
```

Additionally, in Java, integer division occurs when two `int`s are divided, which must yield an `int`.  Consequently, `(9 / 5)` will yield `1`, and `(5 / 9)` will yield `0`.

Make your variables `double`, and use a `double` literal for your constants (or cast one of them as a `double`), to use floating-point division:

```
(9.0 / 5.0)
```

or

```
( (double) 9 / 5)
```